# Support of a fundamental solution of wave equation

Tags: differential-equations, fourier-analysis, schwartz-distributions, wave-equation

The solution of the wave equation
$$
\Box E = \delta
$$
is
$$
E(t,x) = \mathscr{F}^{-1} \left( \frac{\sin (t\lvert \cdot \rvert ) }{\lvert \cdot \rvert} \theta (t) \right)(x)\in\mathcal{S'}(\mathbb{R^{1,n}})
$$
I want to prove using the Paley–Wiener-Shwartz theorem that
$$
supp(E) \subset \{ (t,x), \lvert x \rvert \le t\} 
$$
The problem is that I cannot directly calculate the inverse Fourier transform, it's quite difficult integral. Any hint?

Comment: Hi evedel, and welcome to the MathOverflow. The integral you are searching for is standard: relevant references can be found in this [Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064926/solution-to-square-chi-f/3079988#3079988)

Comment: Thanks for advice. Problem is that I should show that $
supp(E) \subset \{ (t,x), \lvert x \rvert \le t\} 
$ for general $n$ in $\mathbb{R^{1,n}}$. Then according to Schwartz's Paley–Wiener theorem I have to calculate the Fourier-Laplace transformation of $E(t,x)$ for general $n$, but I can't calculate $E(t,x)$ in the general case.

Comment: Oh, I remember now. The explicit formula changes its structure as $n$ and its properties depend also on if $n$ is even (no Huygens principle) or odd (the Huygens principle holds).

Comment: You can also deduce this from the finite propagation speed of the wave equation (for smooth solutions, say), which isn't hard to prove.

Comment: See  Chapter 18 of Duistermaat & Kolk book *Distributions*

Comment: Thank you Christian Remling and Liviu Nicolaescu. Problem solved.

Comment: @evedel: All you need to know is that the Fourier tranform is an entire function which grows no faster than $\exp(t^{-1} |\Im x|)$. See, for example, the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Schwartz's_Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem).